# Is there a way to keep multiple "Find Reference" panes in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When searching for a symbol using Find Reference (or alike) we get only one result pane. So searching for another symbol replaces the results from the previous search.

Is it possible to keep the previous results?

I know R# has this feature, but using R# is not an option, because R# is just too heavy. And so we do not use it. I can extend this limitation to any VS plugin that is as heavy as R#.

Basically, I am asking if there is a light weight plugin that does just that - allows to keep the results of the previous Find References available. Or maybe there is a VS flag for that?

**EDIT 1**

FYI, the Find References option I use produces a pane like this:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I have never noticed that the Find All References context menu option

[image]

produces a pane with the **Keep Results** button:

[image]

What I was doing often is just clicking the References Code Lens hyperlink:

[image]

For some reason I thought both produce the same result and clicking the link was faster than opening a popup. But now I can see they produce different result. I wonder why?

Comment: Just curious: Do you still consider R# too heavy with VS2022? The change to 64 bit has, according to my own experience, improved the situation by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @PMF - TBH - no. I still carry the impressions from the previous versions, but I understand what you are saying. I should give it a try. But I have trained myself to do without R# (the hangover was tough) so I am OK with something small that does just what I need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this button? The "MyClass-References" Window has a button named "Keep results" on top. Enabling it seems to exactly do what you need: Each consecutive "Find references" will open a new tab.

[image: "Keep results"]

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I added the pane I see in my post. There is no such buttons there. How exactly do you get to that pane of yours?

Comment: Oh, I see. The Find References context menu option and the Find References through the Code Lens produce different output panes and the first one does have this button. I have never noticed this difference. Good catch. Thank you.